# why img is not taking full width of parent?

Tags: html, css

```css
.landing{
        position: inherit;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80vh;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .landing  .wrapper + img{
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="landing"> 
  <div class="wrapper"> 
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/350/100/" alt="Our Building">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/350/100/" alt="LOGO"> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

All i want is that image should take full with of its parent , please help me out . Thanks in advance

Comment: `.landing  .wrapper + img` selects an `img` _after_ `.wrapper`, you need `.landing  .wrapper img` to target `img`s _inside_ `.wrapper`

Comment: sorry ,didn't get it

Comment: See the answer by @connexo ;-)

Comment: if you lok at the relationship between the landing and wrapper, the same relationship exists between the wrapper and the img so you do not need the plus - the plus means that the elements are siblings and the image directly follows the wrapper - ie on the same level as each other, whereas your wrapper and img have a parent child relationship.  Just remove the plus and your code will work.  [More info about the adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `first-child` element:

```css
.landing{
    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    z-index: 0;
}

.landing .wrapper img:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="Our Building">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="LOGO">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know this way , but i want do with sibling selector

Comment: You cannot select the first image with any kind of sibling selector.

Answer (score 1):

`.wrapper + img` finds an `img` in this HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<img src="..." />
```

`+`  is the adjacent sibling (or neighbor) selector, and finds the element next on the same DOM level.

If you want to target all `img`s which are descendants of `wrapper`, so use the descendant selector  (space character):

```
.landing  .wrapper img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to target only the first `img` which is a child of `.wrapper`, use a combination of `>` (child selector) and `:first-of-type` pseudo selector:

```
.landing  .wrapper > img:first-of-type {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i want to increase the size of 1st image only

Comment: Added that as the third part.

Comment: I explained that in the first part of the answer. *+ is the NextSibling (or Neighbor) selector, and finds the element next on the same DOM level.*